# Raycast и Collision

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь проецировать яблоко на куб, в режиме редактора. Всё просто - отвожу объект на "безопасное" расстояние от поверхности куба (красная траектория), далее, делаю проекцию на плоскость куба (синяя траектория).

[image: Траектории]

Далее, пытаюсь позиционировать объект по полученным координатам.

[image: Позиционирование]

Получается что яблоко спозиционировалось ровно по своему локальному центру, и вошло на половину в куб.

**Вопрос**: *каким образом можно рассчитать смещение для яблока, чтобы оно легло ровно до касания с поверхностью?*

Как я понимаю, за это отвечает Collision, но, для проекции по любому нужен raycast. В голову приходит только решение в лоб - двигать объект от конца красной траектории в точку рейкаста и смотреть на коллизии, но, имхо, это как то глупо, тем более придётся просчитывать изменения тысячных долей позиции яблока...

Вообще, я знаю Bounds меша яблока, но, ума не приложу, как с помощью него что то расчитать, ведь объект может быть повёрнут, да и по каким осям его смещать однозначно не ясно, рейкаст может успешно "прибивать" яблоко как сверху куба, так и сбоку, ровно как и в любые другие места любого другого меша.

Код этого фрагмента:

```
RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit();
Handles.color=new Color(1f, 0f, 0f);
result += rotation * new Vector3(0, 0, 1f);

Handles.DrawLine(position, result);

Ray ray = new Ray(result, rotation * new Vector3(0, 0, -1)); // генерируем луч в сторону поверхности

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo)) {

    Handles.color=new Color(0f, 0f, 1f);
    Handles.DotCap(0, hitInfo.point, rotation, 0.02f);
    Handles.DrawLine(result, hitInfo.point);

    result = hitInfo.point;

} else {
    result -= rotation * new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить следующие варианты

1. Использовать известное значение "высоты" яблока, это расстояние от его центра до нижней точки, после чего поднять по синему лучу на это расстояние, сложностей больших возникнуть не  должно.
2. Использовать возожность узнать пересекаются ли объекты и использовать метод половинного деления от начально точки до точки куда вы его и так положили.
3. Добавить вес (gravity) и яблоко само упадёт :)